# Gives Error 'Package R does not exist' When I add module(Library) in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have created two modules(libraries). Libraries have jar files. I have an project. Every thing is good But When I add the module(Image Slider) to project, gives 'Package R does not exist' error in the mentioned module.

Whats problem ? and How to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i solved it by adding

```
import android.support.v7.appcompat.R;
```

in every class where the error occured ,i hope it work